# How to configure Terraform to trigger alerts based on log errors for GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm new to `Terraform` and going through its documentation it sounds a bit confused yet, that said, I'd like to know if it is possible to create a `resource` that will trigger an alert based on a specified log file on `GCP`. The rule should be something like "if we get more than 100 errors within 1 hour, trigger it.".

As a start point I was thinking in something like this, but I'm not quite sure where exactly I specify the "error" type in the message itself and the threshold (100 errors/hour).

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "too_many_errors_alerts" {
display_name = "TERRAFORM -- Too many errors alerts"
  enabled      = true

  combiner = "OR"
  conditions {
    display_name = "Too many errors alerts"
    condition_threshold {
      filter          = "metric.type=\"logging.googleapis.com/location/to/logs????" resource.type=\"cloud_run_revision\""
      duration        = "1h"
      comparison      = "COMPARISON_GT"
      threshold_value = 300
      trigger {
        count = 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like a thought if I'm following the right path.

Comment: Have you read: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/monitoring_alert_policy?

Comment: Modify the `threshold_value` to 100 - the `metric.type` will depend on, of course, what you are trying to monitor. Errors to be monitored for exactly *what* would answer that

Answer (score 1):

As a tip, try first on the GCP console because it helps you understand the expected metrics and to point to the right resource.
Monitoring>Alerting>create policy>add condition

You will see an input box where you can find resource type and metric. Type the resource name you want to create your alert for and a dropdown of possible metrics and its description will appear.
[image]

If you click the **Query Editor** button you will see the name of the metrics and resource as Terraform expect it
[image]

So you can add that information in here

```
  filter                = "metric.type=\"pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages\" resource.type=\"pubsub_subscription\" metadata.system_labels.name=\"dead-letter-subscription\""
```

Regarding the condition threshold, duration must be in the next format and threshold_value is to specify the number of errors to want to monitor

```
  duration              = "3600s"
  threshold_value       = 100
```

Bear in mind that duration, only support values that are a multiple of a minute--e.g. 60s, 120s, or 300s